# Elliptical usage of を

Tags: grammar, particle-を, ellipsis

I came across the following elliptical sentence:

> 美しい伝統の国柄を明日の日本へ

How does the particle を work in this case? Is it the end of a clause modifying 明日? Are both, it and the clause preceding へ　arguments (direct and lative) of an implied verb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 「美{うつく}しい伝統{でんとう}の国柄{くにがら}を明日{あす}の日本{にっぽん}へ」

That is not a sentence.  It is a perfectly-formed phrase for a title, headline or motto, but without a verb at the end, I would not call it a sentence.

So, what is the verb that is left unsaid?  It would be the one that logically fits below (in English):

> "to (verb) our beautiful national characteristics into/onto tomorrow's Japan"

Hope you are following me so far.

It would have to be a verb that means "to carry on", "to continue", etc., wouldn't it?

In this case, however, we already know the answer from the website of the group saying 「美しい伝統の国柄を明日の日本へ」.  The answer is here.

http://www.nipponkaigi.org/about/mokuteki

It says in the passage following the above headline:

> 国際化{こくさいか}が進{すす}み、社会{しゃかい}が大きく変動{へんどう}しようとも、常{つね}に揺{ゆ}るがぬ誇{ほこ}り高{たか}い伝統{でんとう}ある国がらを、明日の日本に**伝{つた}えていきたいと思{おも}います**。

Thus, the verb is 「伝{つた}えていく」 ("to keep passing down").

Whenever a word or phrase is left unsaid (which happens frequently in Japanese), that word or phrase would always be a logical one -- one that the readers/listeners could easily infer from the context or situation.